# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Unable to initialize the project due to DB2 error

Tags: db2, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I'm getting the following error while trying to access the Worklight server deployed in my machine:

```
Error 500: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: FWLSE0206E: The project /worklight failed to initialize, because the project database schema for data source jdbc:db2://xxxxx:50000/WRKLGHT is from version N/A, which is not supported by the server from version 6.1.0.00.20131126-0630. Use the Worklight ant tasks to upgrade the project database schema. [project worklight]
```

Comment: You will need to explain what you have done with your database setup. Right now it sounds like you are trying to connect to a database not created with Worklight 6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow what the error message suggests.

Make sure that the database schema you use for your DB2 database is one that fits Worklight 6.1

- [Upgrading from a previous version](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_srvr_prod_postinstall_alt_dbs.html)
- [How to manually update the database](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_srvr_prod_postinstall_alt_dbs.html)
- [How to configure the database using Ant](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_configure_dbs.html)
- [Make sure that you have properly configured your application server for working with DB2](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_configuring_websphere_application_server_for_db2_manually.html)
- [Also make sure that you have properly set up DB2...](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_setting_up_your_db2_database_manually.html)