# Worklight Server - Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

Continuous from previous question, [IBM Worklight 6.1 - Project fails to initialize because the project database schema is from version N/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316477/ibm-worklight-6-1-project-fails-to-initialize-because-the-project-database-sch), I able to fix the problem. But the nightmare won't stop there. A new errors coming out!!! After i restart my web sphere server, I got this error message in my browser.

```
    Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization 
    failed. Logged Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: FWLSE4010E: The project 
'xxxx' failed to initialise, because the project WAR file is not supported by the server 
from version 6.1.0.00.20131126-0630. Use the migration tool to upgrade the project WAR 
file. [project xxxx]
```

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

Because your Worklight Studio version is not 6.1.0;
Use Worklight Studio 6.1 to build your project and then take the generated .war file from the your-projec\bin project. Deploy this .war file to your application server.

Read the relevant topics all the way: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/deploy/c_deploy_wl_project.html