# Worklight Server - Failed to deploy adapter 'LinkAccount.adapter'.

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

From the previous problematic and devastation in installation worklight server into our websphere, [IBM Worklight 6.1 - Project fails to initialize because the project database schema is from version N/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316477/ibm-worklight-6-1-project-fails-to-initialize-because-the-project-database-sch/22369052#22369052) , we discover new problem after that catastrophic event. First we got this error message

```
Error 500: javax.servlet.
ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: FWLSE4010E: The project 'xxxx' failed to initialize, because the project WAR file is not supported by the server from version 6.1.0.00.20131126-0630. Use the migration tool to upgrade the project WAR file. [project xxxx]
```

Then we use the migration tool to ugrade follow from this guideline --> [http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devenv/r_migrating_old_wl_project_to_new_wl_server.html
We managed to deployed the war file](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devenv/r_migrating_old_wl_project_to_new_wl_server.html%20We%20managed%20to%20deployed%20the%20war%20file).

Next we want to deploy the adaptor, we encounter this error message

```
Failed to deploy adapter 'LinkAccount.adapter'. The 'adapter' version '6.1.0.00.20131219-1900' is different than the version of the Worklight project '6.0.0'. Use Worklight Studio '6.0.0' to build and deploy the application.
```

When we check the version at the console (Worklight Server), the project war version is 6.0.0. Both Studio and Server is in the same version 6.1 but need to do the migration process which downgrade the project into 6.0.0. 
Do missing something during the installation of Worklight server?

Our Worklight Studio (eclipse)

[image: Our Worklight Studio (eclipse)]

Worklight Server version

[image: Worklight Server version]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the worklight console application from WAS (Websphere application server)
2. Stop WAS.
3. Redeploy war file that containing worklight console
4. Start WAS

You need to rebuild the .wlapp and .adapter files in your studio version that have a same version with worklight server.

Comment: can you explain more about your solution?
the 'server' u mean is it a WAS server?

Comment: I guess, Idan Adar is correct about something is missing. maybe your 1st build of Worklight Console WAR file is not from Workloght Studio 6.1

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Worklight Studio 6.1
2. Deploy Worklight Server 6.1
3. Build your project in Worklight Studio 6.1 (adapters, app)
4. Deploy generated .war file in the server
5. Deploiy generated .adapter and .wlap in the server

Build everything with the new version and deploy the new artifacts in the same version.

If you are running on your application server several instances of Worklight Server, make sure you deploy to the correct one.

Comment: We build using Worklight Studio 6.1 (Project,Adaptor) as you can see from the screenshot given.
We using the same war,adaptor file to deploy into the WL Server. Ony one instance of WL server.

Comment: Obviously something is amiss because your adapter is not of the same version.

Answer (score 0):

- Delete the contents in your project bin folder.
- Build and deploy all the adapters.
- Build and deploy the application.
- open worklight console